# add 'normal' data along with files in XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that sends formdata to a php file to then be processed.

The formdata is an array of files, however I am now wanting to send some strings as well that contain the file's original modified dateTime. I thought this would just be a simple one-liner but it's not working and I'm not sure why.

The object code:

```
var app = app || {};

(function(o){
    "use strict"

    var ajax, getFormData, setProgress;

    ajax = function(data){
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), uploaded;
        xmlhttp.addEventListener('onreadystatechange', function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readystate === 4){
                if(xmlhttp.status === 200){
                    $('#pt').html("Upload complete");
                } else {
                    $('#pt').html("Upload Error, please try again");
                }   
            }
        });
        xmlhttp.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
            var percent;
            if(event.lengthComputable === true){
                percent = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
                setProgress(percent);
            }
        });
        xmlhttp.open('POST', o.options.processor);
        xmlhttp.send(data);
    }
    getFormData = function(src){
        var data = new FormData(), i;
        for(i=0;i<src.length;i++){
            data.append('file[]',src[i]);
Here -----> // fileDate = new Date(src[i].lastModified)
----------> // data.append(fileDate)
        }
        data.append('formSent',true);
        return data;
    }
    setProgress = function(val){
        $('#pb').animate({width:val+"%"},10);
        $('#pt').html(val+"%");
    }

    o.uploader = function(opt){
        o.options = opt;
        if(o.options.files !== undefined){
            ajax(getFormData(o.options.files.files));
        }
    }
}(app));
```

Calling the object:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#progressContainer').slideDown(10);
            var f = $('#file'),
                pb = $('#pb'),
                pt = $('#pt');
                fileDate = new Date(f.files[0].lastModified)
            alert(fileDate)
            // Upload file to server
            app.uploader({
                files:f,
                progressBar:pb,
                progressText:pt,
                processor:'scripts/php/upload.php'
            });
        });
```

I've been working a lot in Python recently and my Javascript is pretty rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there, you just need to set the name of the parameter you want to pass:

```
data.append("myParameterName", fileDate);
```

Since it's a date value, you might wanna convert it to a milliseconds-since-UNIX-epoch value (`fileDate.valueOf()`) or an ISO string (`fileDate.toISOString()`) though.

[Further reading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#Example)

Comment: [slaps self in face]. I completely forgot it takes a key:value pair. It works now :)